# How to crop sub-part of the image?

Tags: c#, bitmap, emgucv

I need to crop sub-part from image.

For example,I have this image:

[image]

I need to crop the part of the image that in the red frame,
I have four coordinates of the frame corners,

Any idea how to implement it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you only want what is inside the red frame?

Comment: Yes only the content of the frame

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Graphics.DrawImage();`

```
    Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(...);
    Bitmap src = Image.FromFile(fileName) as Bitmap;
    Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);

    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
    {
         g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
```

And if need, you can save target to a new file.

Also See : [C# Tutorial - Image Editing: Saving, Cropping, and Resizing](https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/620/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing)

Comment: I need only the content of the frame